# load multiple images on click using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load multiple images into a DIV using jquery or javascript.

for example:

when `image1` is clicked, the `image1` will be loaded into DIV container,
when `image2` is clicked, the `image2` will be loaded into DIV container and `image1` is removed.
when `image3` is clicked, the `image3` will be loaded into DIV container and the previous image is removed.
and so on so forth...

I have the following code which doesn't do anything:

javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function changeImg() {
    document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML="<img src='badges/legal2.png' />";
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
  <img style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left;" src="badges/legal1.png" width="54" height="123" onclick="changeImg();" />
  <img style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left;" src="badges/legal2.png" width="54" height="123" onclick="changeImg();"/>

<div id="apDiv1"><img id="img1" src="badges/legal1.png" width="73" height="140" /></div>
```

COULD SOMEONE PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS?

EDIT:

I changed my code to the following and now it loads only one image.. I need to know how i can load the specific image once its clicked using only one javascript function:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function changeImg() {
    document.getElementById("apDiv1").innerHTML="<img src='badges/legal2.png' />";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add images to class "myImg". The image src in div will be changed on click. Refer to the HTML code:

```
<img class="myImg" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left;" src="badges/legal1.png" width="54" height="123" />
  <img class="myImg" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; float:left;" src="badges/legal2.png" width="54" height="123"/>
<div id="apDiv1"><img id="showImg" width="73" height="140" /></div>
```

When document is ready,

```
$(".myImg").click(function(){
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#showImg").attr("src",imgSrc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Edited to remove `onclick="changeImg();"` from HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

The `innerHTML` is the html that is inside a tag. So for example, inner HTML of `<div id="someid">some html</div>` is `some html`.

The `img` tag doesn't have an end tag, so it can't have inner HTML.

You want to use something like this:

```
document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("img", "badges/legal2.png")
```

Also, note that **the id attribute is unique**, that is, you can't use the same value for `id` in more than one element. Your code assigns the id of `apDiv1` to both the `<div>` and the `<img>` tags. It looks like you meant to use the id of `img` for your `<img>` tag since that is what you used in the JavaScript.

Comment: Could you set up a fiddle on jsfiddle.net that shows what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find element with id "img1" and there is no element with this id.

Make sure all id's are unique and put correct id in document.getElementById() function. If you are changing innerHtml you should look up for div which wraps your img tag.

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/gL6qC/

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('img').on('click', function(){
       $('#apDiv1').html($(this).clone()); 
    });
});
```